# delete a specific row of a table using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have designed a table that will display data something like this:

```
ID  name    Delete
1   abc     Delete
2   def     Delete
```

the code used for the above display is

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("abc","abc","abc","abc");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM student");
echo "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-hover'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>name</th>
<th>delete</th>   
</tr>
</thead>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
echo "<tbody data-link='row' class='rowlink'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><a href='delete.php'>Delete</a></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</tbody>";    
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

code for delete.php

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("abc","abc","abc","abc");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM student WHERE id='$id'");
mysqli_close($con);
header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

View of database is

```
Id  name
1   abc
2   cdf
```

the problem is that it is not deleting the data and is also not showing any error

Comment: You haven't defined `$id` in your deletion code; *or have you?* It's not shown/included.

Comment: You're also putting quotes around an integer and failing to check your function returns.

Comment: Making your delete script a simple GET is definitely going to kick you in the rump and stomp all over your ribs. NEVER put a destructive operation like that behind a get - consider what happens if your browser decides to prefetch all the links on the page. "oops".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that according to the [HTTP standard](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616), the `GET` method shouldn't be used for modifying data in the database. Therefore you should use a form with `method="POST"`, like

```
echo '<td><form method="POST" action="delete.php"><input type="hidden" value="'.$row['id'].'"><input type="submit" value="Delete"></form></td>';
```

Then for **delete.php**, for safety purposes, you should look into using [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they much safer*. I have included an example below.

---

***Here is a prepared statements example:***

```
<?php 
$DB_HOST = "xxx";
$DB_NAME = "xxx";
$DB_USER = "xxx";
$DB_PASS = "xxx";

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$con = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);

$id = (int)$_POST['id'];

$update = $con->prepare("DELETE FROM student WHERE id = ?");
$update->bind_param('i', $id);
$update->execute();
```

Answer (score -2):

Add a `GET` parameter to your link:

```
echo "<td><a href='delete.php?id='".$row['id']."'>Delete</a></td>";
```

Then catch it in your `delete.php` query:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM student WHERE id='".$id."'");
```

Comment: Using `GET` is never a good idea when modifying data in the database. Using for example a pre-fetch browser extension, you will automatically wipe out your database.

Comment: Why is not a good idea ? 
You can clean $id by intval($id) and then it's safe.

Comment: @CarcaBot I have not even mentioned sql injection yet, I am merely talking about a browser following all links automatically.

Comment: @jeroen You've got it on "automatic"? *Sweet*