# why i m giving success even the id and/or username does not exist in database

Tags: php, mysqli

I m trying to code a deletation page, but when i type id and username and click delete, it gives me the message "success" even if the id and/or username not exist in database and if i type correct id and username is delete from database
with message "success" how to fix this please? thank you

```
<?php require ('server.php');?>

<?php

$uniqueid=$_GET['uniqueid'];
$username=$_GET['username'];


if(isset($_GET['uniqueid'], $_GET['username'])){

$sql= "DELETE FROM users WHERE uniqueid='$uniqueid' AND username='$username'";   

    if($sql)
        echo "succces";

} 

else {

    echo 'ERROR';
}

mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

Comment: why did you put the code in comment? just edit it

Comment: you are not executing sql, there is no mysqli query statement here

Comment: so what to do please, can you help me to add the command mysqli to my deletation page

Comment: [mysqli_query](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) should help here. But only if you are [mysqli_connect](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)ed.

Comment: _“so what to do please”_ - to do: Go work through some proper beginner’s tutorials/books, and learn some basics first. SO is not the place to come for private tutoring, and explaining the basics over and over and over again is not what we should have to do here in the first place.

Comment: <?php require ('server.php');?>

<?php

$uniqueid=$_GET['uniqueid'];
$username=$_GET['username'];

$sql= "DELETE FROM users WHERE uniqueid='$uniqueid' AND username='$username'";   

 if (mysqli_query($db, $sql)) {
 
echo "succces";
}

else {
 
    echo 'ERROR';
}

mysqli_close($db);
?>

what about now please

Comment: i'm just need help

Comment: You never execute the query: when you do, a success means that the SQL has executed correctly, not that records have been deleted; if it has executed correctly, then [affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php) will tell you whether records were deleted or not

Comment: tell me how to excute the query please

Comment: Please help, can't move on

Comment: @MarkBaker can you hammer this one with https://stackoverflow.com/q/26107666/2943403

Comment: still not working !

Answer (score 0):

let's break down you code :

- you are using mysqli, you may have to look into the use PDO instead
  it have a way bigger database list interaction whereas mysqli only
  got one.
- you have no statement for running your sql statment, for now **$sql** is justplain text

the fix way for you code:

```
<?php
$uniqueid=$_GET['uniqueid'];
$username=$_GET['username'];

if(isset($_GET['uniqueid'], $_GET['username']))
{
    $sql= $BD->("DELETE FROM users WHERE uniqueid='$uniqueid' AND username='$username'"); 
    /*$BD is you connection to the database*/

    if($sql) echo "succces";
    else 
    {
        echo 'ERROR';
    }
}
else
{
    echo 'no id or username';
}

$sql->closeCursor();?>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot man! but i m getting this error please Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in C:\xampp\htdocs\registration\delete.php on line 10

Comment: can i just use sqli please, i'm still getting success even if the user does not exist i appreciated your help and i hope you can still help me please thank you a lot

Comment: any suggestions please