# How to delete a row from a WordPress custom database?

Tags: database, wordpress, forms

I have a custom database and a code that displays the table data and I want a button on the right side of the table that will delete a row that it's attached to from the table.

```
<?php //get_header(); 

global $wpdb; 
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "hubaya_wallet_users";
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name");

echo '<h1>PAY USERS</h1><br><br>

<table border="1"> 
  <tr> 
  <th>ID</th> 
  <th>ROLE</th> 
  <th>BALANCE</th>
  <th>REG DATE</th>
  <th>Mobile Number</th> ';

  foreach ( $result as $print ) { ?>
  <tr> 
    <td><?php echo $print->user_id; ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $print->user_role; ?> </td> 
    <td> <?php echo $print->balance ; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $print->created_date; ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $print->phone_no; ?> </td> 
  </tr> 
  <?php } 
  ?>

</table>
```

I want a button attached to each row that on click will delete the row. I tried adding a table like this:

```
<td><input name="del" type="submit" value= "echo $print->user_id; ?>"> </td>
```

Now I don't know how to set its action to a function below.

```
function del(){
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . $_POST['table'];
    $mss = intval($_POST['del']);
    $wpdb->delete( $table_name, [ 'id' => $mss] );
}
```

I've also tried creating a separate form where I will have to type in everything and then submit but still failed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [delete a specific row of a table using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26107666/delete-a-specific-row-of-a-table-using-php)

Comment: As a side note, using `$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . $_POST['table'];` isn't probably very safe. A malicious user could craft a POST request to delete random stuff from any database table that way.

Comment: No, im using wordpress and the codea are in the plugin i made. Im displaying the form function in an admin menu and trying to delete from there.   And thanks for the advice, this is on the admin side and its only for testing